# Flutter, open universal link after redirect for external app

Tags: flutter, url, hyperlink, external, universal

We are developing app for affiliate services, CPA networks gave us marketing links (that customers should use to redirect to web shop), however I can't figure it out, how to trigger universal link to open relevant app after redirect is finished.

For example, CPA network gave as a link to Aliexpress, let it be something like this for example

https://ourcpapartner.com/link/to/aliexpress?params

And we open link with following code using url_launcher

```
      if (await canLaunch('https://ourcpapartner.com/link/to/aliexpress?params')) {
        await launch('https://ourcpapartner.com/link/to/aliexpress?params');
      } else {
        throw ('Redirect failed');
      }
```

With Safari, there are no problems, but with Google Chrome nothing simply happens, after opening that link, it instantly redirects to final url - Aliexpress.com, and now it should open app (if it's installed of course), but nothing is happening, however, once you click on something (e.g product) then app is opened and affiliate tracking is messed up.

It does open app as intented if you click direct link on our website.

I might consider to use WebView instead (so it does not depend on third party browser specifications), but how it would be possible to open local apps then? We can't just hard code every app we need to open with deeplink as we got hundred of different offers.

Comment: as you had mentioned if the app is not installed then redirect the link to install the app , to obtain this funcitonality you will have to use dynamic links. do refer: https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_dynamic_links

Comment: Your solution has nothing to do with my task, i dont need to prompt to install partner apps, i need to make universal links work after final redirect